# Blender 2.8 removed use_environment_light API, what to use instead?

Tags: python, scripting

So I found at the very bottom of [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/change_log.html?highlight=use_environment_light) page that Blender removed the old `use_enviroment_light` API from `bpy.types.WorldLighting`. I have some code that used this API as follows:

```
bpy.context.scene.world.light_settings.use_environment_light = True
```

I wonder how I can update this code to keep using environment light in my rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `use_environment_light` was part of the settings for the world when the *Blender Internal* render engine was used. This render engine has been removed in Blender 2.80 and replaced by Eevee. Like Cycles, Eevee uses the nodes based system for the world settings. Enabling environment lighting isn't necessary, it's always on.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Is there a way to change the environment light intensity in Eevee? I guess it's pretty low by default since my rendered images look very dark for now.

Comment: @ZhengyuanDong Yes, it's the strength value in the world tab.

Comment: Do I change it using `bpy.context.world.surface.strength = 3.0` for exmaple?

Comment: I cannot find the strength attribute under `bpy.context.world`. From the graphics interface I can tell that strength under world tab uses shader nodes. But how can I modify it in python code? I am new to Blender and would really appreciate it if you can help!

Comment: @ZhengyuanDong It's `bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes['Background'].inputs['Strength'].default_value`.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!